# Text lable location

Tags: pine-script

I wrote a RSI ADX Combo indicator that generates a Buy/Sell signal.
The Buy/Sell text however appears within the indicator.
My question:
Is it possible to locate the Buy/Sell signals above or below a candle ? in the chart area

I tried different location settings like above/below, top/bottom ect but no matter what I try the result remains the same
Regards

My Code: https://www.tradingview.com/script/ETNUUzLd-RSI-ADX-COMBO-V1/

Comment: Could you please specify the context and library/framework and programming language in the question. "Text label location" can mean anything from formatting html forms to a framework-specific question such as yours.

Comment: Hi Tuure, I used pinescript, see code at https://www.tradingview.com/script/ETNUUzLd-RSI-ADX-COMBO-V1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pinescript with overlay=false all the drawing will be in a separate window.
With version 5, unfortunately you can't draw on both panels.

If you want to draw all in the top panel, to be able to draw above or under the candle, add overlay=true in your indicator declaration..

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just want to draw my signals in the top panel below or above the candle